# ValidationError in mongoose in Node.js even after defining all the fields correctly?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, bson

I am storing my New product data to the MongoDB using mongoose in Node.js but on submitting it giving me Validation error

This is how it looks:

[image]

Here is the product model code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  productId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  OriginalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  images: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  specifications: {
    Mesurement: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    Material: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    Color: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    ColorVariant: {
      type: [String],
    },
    Size: {
      type: [String],
    },
    Work: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    StitchType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    Occasion: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    PrintPattern: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    SupplierSKU: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    Supplier: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    CountryOfOrigin: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    CareGuide: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

Here is the Function code:

```
exports.addProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { newProduct } = req.body;
    const newProd = Product({
      productId: newProduct.productId,
      name: newProduct.name,
      category: newProduct.category,
      price: newProduct.price,
      OriginalPrice: newProduct.OriginalPrice,
      Images: newProduct.Images,
      description: newProduct.description,
      specifications: {
        Mesurements: newProduct.Mesurements,
        Material: newProduct.Material,
        Color: newProduct.Color,
        ColorVariant: newProduct.ColorVariant,
        Size: newProduct.Size,
        Work: newProduct.Work,
        StitchType: newProduct.StitchType,
        Occasion: newProduct.Occasion,
        printPattern: newProduct.printPattern,
        SupplierSKU: newProduct.SupplierSKU,
        supplier: newProduct.supplier,
        CountryOfOrigin: newProduct.CountryOfOrigin,
        CareGuide: newProduct.CareGuide,
      }
    });
    await newProd.save();
    res.json({
      data: true
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

### the error:

ValidationError: products validation failed: specifications.Supplier: Path `specifications.Supplier` is required., specifications.PrintPattern: Path `specifications.PrintPattern` is required., specifications.Mesurement: Path `specifications.Mesurement` is required., name: Path `name` is required., category: Path `category` is required., price: Path `price` is required., OriginalPrice: Path `OriginalPrice` is required., description: Path `description` is required., specifications.Material: Path `specifications.Material` is required., specifications.Color: Path `specifications.Color` is required., specifications.Work: Path `specifications.Work` is required., specifications.StitchType: Path `specifications.StitchType` is required., specifications.Occasion: Path `specifications.Occasion` is required., specifications.SupplierSKU: Path `specifications.SupplierSKU` is required., specifications.CountryOfOrigin: Path `specifications.CountryOfOrigin` is required., specifications.CareGuide: Path `specifications.CareGuide` is required.
at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Priya\OneDrive\Desktop\Client Site\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3087:32)
at C:\Users\Priya\OneDrive\Desktop\Client Site\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2880:17
at C:\Users\Priya\OneDrive\Desktop\Client Site\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1350:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Comment: `supplier: newProduct.supplier,` maybe this line should be `Supplier: newProduct.supplier,`

Comment: @SuleymanSah   Yes it is also a small mistake done by me but this did not fix this error, it's still there : (

Comment: can you add the request body to the question using `console.log(req.body)` before save?

Comment: @SuleymanSah   you are right brother i am not getting anything from `req.body` and that's the reason for the error now it fixed thanks for the suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I did not send any data from the client side and I was just clicking the submit button to get it saved to the database, but now it is fixed.